# How do I identify a what kind of power connector for AC mains is on a product?

Tags: ac, connector, mains

I see an AC mains input but I have no idea what kind of cable it goes to, how do I find the cable type so I can design around that? (Or conversely I have a cable and I don't know what type it is)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look for IEC320 reference tables, the connector should match one of the international standards. Once you identify the connector you can search for it. If not, it is a custom cable and the manufacturer will need to be contacted.

> The first edition of IEC 320 (later renumbered IEC 60320) was
> published in 1970.
> Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320)

This is what a table looks like

[image]
Source: https://www.stayonline.com/reference-iec320.aspx

## Edit:

Another good resource https://www.plugsocketmuseum.nl/ApplConn_overview.html

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the IEC connectors @laptop2d listed, there's a few others that are also in common use.

Ceeform connectors are frequently used where high power and/or water resistance are needed.  There's a whole series of them for 1/2/3 phase connections at different voltage and current levels.

[image: Ceeform Inlet Connector]
[image: Ceeform Plugs]

Neutrik PowerCon connectors are also becoming more common, particularly on professional audio devices

[image: Neutrik PowerCon Inlet]
[image: Neutrik PowerCon]