# Where do I find those AC mains connectors?

Tags: pcb-design, connector, mains

I am currently designing a "smart" power strip for aquariums and cant find an PCB mounted wall outlet connector like the image shows, it would be used to connect the load and not for powering the board. 
[image]

Comment: That one is not an IEC standard socket, you might want to use a standard one like a C7, C8 or one with a ground: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/393775/how-do-i-identify-a-what-kind-of-power-connector-for-ac-mains-is-on-a-product/393776#393776

Comment: The trend in Europe is towards earthed sockets.  This socket will be difficult to market in Europe as it is not possible to get it CE marked which makes retail sales questionable.  The mating CEE 7/16 plug will fit into many of the European earthed and legacy sockets which is why it was designed and panel mount versions of these are available though most are now only in earthed varieties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard for this style of plug CEE 7/16, however the standard did not specify a socket, only a plug. This cannot be found at major distributors (only plugs)